# Proving OR is commutative with SSReflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm trying to work through some foundational logic stuff, mainly from the book [Using Z: Specification, Refinement, Proof](http://usingz.com/) but also trying to learn more about Coq. One of the first proofs in the book *Using Z* mentioned above is that logical-or is commutative, `P \/ Q => Q \/ P`. The book uses natural deduction tree notation, so it suffices to assume P, then introduce Q or P, or else assume Q and then introduce Q or P. I have translated this to Coq with whatever you'd call the standard library like so:

```
Theorem disj_comm : forall P Q : Prop, P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.
Proof.
  intros P Q H.
  destruct H. right. apply H.
  left. apply H.
Qed.
```

You see something similar here. Anyway, trying to translate this to SSReflect, I got kind of stuck:

```
Theorem disj_comm' : forall P Q : Prop, P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.
Proof.
  move => P Q H.
  case H.
  right. (* isn't there a better approach here? *)
Abort.
```

I looked through the [SSReflect reference I found](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html) and didn't see anything that obviously looked like it was trying to replace use of `left` and `right`. What's the right way to encode this proof in SSReflect?

**Edit**: I have the following proof now using SSreflect:

```
(* And here's disj_comm in ssreflect *)
Theorem disj_comm' : forall P Q : Prop, P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.
Proof.
  move => P Q H.
  destruct H.
  right.
  by [].
  left.
  by [].
Qed.
```

I feel like this is rather wordy. Is there a better way to do this with SSreflect?

Comment: I feel like the ssreflect way would be to apply the proper constructor: `apply or_introl`. But there's no reason not to use `left`/`right` in such cases.

Comment: @Ptival how would I discover `or_introl` while attempting the proof? (Actually, in trying to apply your advice, I still got stuck, so if you have time to give a more detailed answer, I would appreciate it!)

Comment: `left` and `right` _are_ idiomatic in SSReflect proofs, `or_into(l/r)` are not.

Comment: @AntonTrunov with the edit, do you find my new proof to be idiomatic of SSreflect?

Comment: @DanielLyons To answer your question about finding the constructors: first you can use `Locate "\/".` which will tell you that it stands for "Logic.or". Then you can `Print Logic.or.` which will show you the definition, including the two constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say an idiomatic solution in SSReflect would look both on tactic and syntactic level like so:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma disj_comm P Q : P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.
Proof. by case; [right | left]. Qed.
```

Comment: This is embarassing for me, but I just tried it in my Coq (8.10.1) and I get `Error: Not an inductive product.`

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is that I had `forall P Q : Prop, P \/ Q -> Q -> P`, so I need `move => P Q.` before `by case; [right | left].`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The SSReflect style prefers to put non-dependent parameters to the left of the colon, i.e. `Lemma disj_comm P Q : P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.` is preferable to `Lemma disj_comm : forall P Q, P \/ Q -> Q \/ P.`